# One extreme outlier fitted value that is replaced by another when dropped

Tags: regression, python, predictive-models, least-squares

I have an OLS model with a very bad prediction score - when I decided to test for heteroskedasticity, it turned out my model's predictions include one incredibe outlier - it looks like my fitted values plotted against residuals are all clustered in one cloud of dots, except there is one dot that has a way higher fitted value and residual, so high that the entire cloud of other dots has to be confined in the corner of the screen for this one dot to fit in the other. What's odd is that when i look that outlier up, it has no special, crazy qualities - very average X's across the board. Odder yet, if I manually drop it from my spreadsheet, another one takes its place, always in the row before or after the one I just dropped, with almost the same exact proportion of rows below to rows above. This is particularly puzzling, because I am using train-test split in python:
`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)`
which is supposed to shuffle values by default, so there is literally no significance to the position of the outliers. Why does it do that? How can it be remedied? The data, for those who want to replicate it, is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fa2fsgeRKy8Iodpt6FfDzf9oCxyNph5gIB-uD3T_ktQ/edit?usp=sharing
My entire code is here:

````py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
# Read the data
df = pd.read_excel("final.xlsx")

# Assuming df is your DataFrame
y = df["rent"]
x = df.drop(
    [
        "rent",
        "Index",
        "pets_deposit",
        "Commute_nonrush",
        "Commute_rush",
        "school3",
        "walk-score",
        "bike-score",
        "lease_term",
        "transit-score",
        "cats_allowed",
        "pets_allowed",
        "deposit_missing",
        "application_fee_missing",
        "application_fee",
        "school2",
        "garbageincluded",
        "pets_allowed_deposit",
        "arrests",
    ],
    axis=1,
)


matrix = x.corr()
with open("OLS/matrix.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(matrix))

# Calculate VIF for each variable
vif = pd.DataFrame()
vif["variables"] = x.columns
vif["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(x.values, i) for i in range(x.shape[1])]
with open("OLS/vif.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(vif))

# Split the data into training and testing sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Perform the backward elimination
cols = list(x_train.columns)
p = []
x_1 = x_train[cols]
model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_1).fit()

# Calculate residuals
residuals = model.resid

# Find the index of the observation with the largest absolute residual
outlier_index = np.argmax(np.abs(residuals))

print(f"The index of the outlier is: {outlier_index}")

# If you want to see the entire row of the outlier in the DataFrame
print(df.iloc[outlier_index])

# print the prediction of the outlier
print(model.predict(x_1.iloc[outlier_index]))

# Create a scatterplot for residuals
plt.scatter(model.fittedvalues, residuals)
plt.xlabel("Fitted Values")
plt.ylabel("Residuals")
plt.title("Residuals vs Fitted Values")
plt.show()


selected_features_BE = cols
summary_str = model.summary().as_text()
with open("OLS/summary_OLS.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(summary_str)

# Subset the test data to include only the selected features
x_test_BE = x_test[selected_features_BE]

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = model.predict(x_test_BE)

# Calculate and print the Mean Squared Error (MSE)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print(mse)
with open("OLS/mse.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(mse))

# Calculate and print the R-squared score
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
with open("OLS/r2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(r2))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Are you running regression diagnostics to identify/drop overly influential observations, and then re-running with dropped outliers?  This entails looking at the Studentized residuals, jackknife residuals, Cook's distance, leverage residuals, DFFITS, DFBETAS, and comparing them with threshold values to identify and drop overly influential observations from your model.  VIFs can be used to look at multicollinearity between input predictors.

To sidestep regression diagnostics, you could try median regression (quantile regression), which will likely tone down the overly influential observations.  In addition, hopefully, you looked at univariate prediction models to get a handle on which predictors are meaningful by themselves.  Another way to "smooth out" these issues when looking for a relationship is to run univariate Somers' D between the x-y pairs, to get a handle on univariate directionality and association.

Comment: Thanks a lot - unfortunately, I am stuck with OLS - the topic of the thing I am writing is OLS specifically. I tried some of the things you are suggesting, not others, but I am not sure your answer applies - the issue, as I stated, is not that there is an outlier that has crazy X values that generate crazy Y values - not at all. In fact, the issue is not a datapoint at all. The issue is that an incredibly normal datapoint generates a fitted outlier, and that if I drop it, it is replaced with another outlier in the same row number in the database. That last part is very relevant.